# Increment the numeric ending of a String by 1, using: Void increment(char[] referenceNumber)

Tags: c#, string, increment

Please help me with this interview question I faced recently, every help will be appreciated.

> Please implement in C# the function that increments a `string` based on below rules:
>
> 1. It should take the string of unknown length and increment the numeric ending of that string by 1.
> 2. If numeric ending is overflown it must be reset
> 3. Don't use regular expressions.
>
> Examples:
>
> - 000002 ▶ 000003
> - DRI000EDERS0RE99999 ▶ DRI000EDERS0RE00000

Comment: What have you tried? please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to skin this cat. I think I would actually rely on c# ability to treat char like int, and manipulate the characters rather than trying to parse an int out of it, increment it then format it back

```
string s = "abcd999";
string ca = s.ToCharArray();

for(int i = ca.Length - 1; i>= 0 && char.IsDigit(ca[i]); i--){
  if(ca[i] == '9')
    ca[i] = '0';
  else {
    ca[i]++;
    break;
  }
}

return new string(ca);
```

We turn the string into a char array for easy manipulation then skip backwards over it from end to start. We want to stop looping when we hit a non digit or the string start. Then the logic is simple counting like a kid does. If we are on 9 we go back to 0 (the "bump up the next one will maybe be done by the next pass of the loop), otherwise we increment the char by one and quit:

- `4` becomes `5`,
- `19` becomes `10` becomes `20`,
- `abc9999` becomes `abc9990` then `abc9900` then `abc9000` then `abc0000` then the loop quits on the non digit `c`